# Boost bjam tutorial keeps looking for the wrong mcvs version

Tags: python, c++, boost

Everytime I try to run bjams tutorial python script with the following command:

```
bjam -j4 toolset=msvc-9.0 address-model=64
```

It crashes with this error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib'

        call "C:\Users\Wouter\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_9.0_vcvarsall_x86_amd64
.cmd" >nul
```

Which makes a lot of sense, since in the directory is only a boost_python-vc90-mt-gd-1_58.lib.

Renaming it (obviously) doesn't work and gives a PDB incompatibility error.

I've taken msvc 12.0 out of my PATH, and replaced it with 9.0, same error. My user-config.jam currently only contains "using msvc-9.0 ;", the python install seems to get found correctly without the "using python" stuff.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Full cmd output: http://pastebin.com/kpiNih2F